# BaseAdapter GetView returning NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

This is my Base Adapter and I am trying to inflate a GridView with Images from drawable. As it turns out, it returns NullPointerExceptipn. But when I change getCount() return value to 0, it does not show exception anymore but the gridview does not show up. I have taken out the log of build_list and it has data in it.

```
public class BuildingListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<Building> build_list = new ArrayList<Building>();

public BuildingListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Building> build_list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    context = c;
    this.build_list.addAll(build_list);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return build_list.size();
}

@Override
public Building getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return build_list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("CheckifRun", "true");
    Building building = this.getItem(position);
    ImageView img_view = new ImageView(convertView.getContext());
    int resID = convertView.getResources().getIdentifier(building.getBuild_img(), "drawable", "com.vapp.yangonuniversity");
    Log.v("resourceID", Integer.toString(resID));
    img_view.setImageResource(resID);
    img_view.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    img_view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return img_view;
}


}
```

Comment: At which line you getting exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change getView method to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("CheckifRun", "true");
    Building building = this.getItem(position);
    ImageView img_view = new ImageView(context);
    int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(building.getBuild_img(), "drawable", "com.vapp.yangonuniversity");
    Log.v("resourceID", Integer.toString(resID));
    img_view.setImageResource(resID);
    img_view.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    img_view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return img_view;
}
```

you need your context for creating `ImageView` and get data from Resource

**what have Changed ?**

```
ImageView img_view = new ImageView(context);
```

and

```
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(building.getBuild_img(), "drawable", "com.vapp.yangonuniversity");
```

**Update**

you got `OutOfMemomryException`,

**Why**?

OutofMemory occurs when your app exceeds memory allocated in heap. The bitmap is too large to fit in memory ie heap

**How to fix this issue?**

you can search about that in google to find many related question, for start you can see:

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: It did fix the error but it's now showing "out Of Memory Error"

Comment: Thanks youy so much. It helps me a lot